# Python script to post a picture with text on a facebook wall

Tags: python, scripting

As the title says. Is it possible to write a Python script that posts a jpg picture on a facebook wall along with a text string? If it is possible. How do I start?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Facebook Graph  API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

You can find documentation for posting text and an attachment on a wall [here](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#put-wall-post). Make sure to authenticate a user first though. You can find the documentation on the same page

The code will then look pretty simple:

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_token')

attachment =  {
    'name': 'Link name'
    'link': 'http://www.example.com/',
    'caption': 'Check out this example',
    'description': 'This is a longer description of the attachment',
    'picture': 'http://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg'
}

graph.put_wall_post(message='Check this out...', attachment=attachment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with POST :

```
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/ID_PAGE/photos?
url=URL_PICTURE
&message="YOUR_MESSAGE"
&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```